# Draw until the end of a box

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx

Is it possible to draw a line from n2 spanning the blah text and \blinditemize without hardcoding the length?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.70\textwidth}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture},
    fluffy/.style={fill opacity=0.1,circle,fill,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=1mm}}

\blindtext

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l @{~} |X| @{}}
    \cline{2-2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(l1.base)]
        \node[fluffy,label={[name=l1]left:n1-label}] at (0,0) (n1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
                          & \textcolor{red}{title1} \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}   \\
    \cline{2-2}
                          &
    Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah
    \blinditemize
    \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}   \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(l2.base)]
        \node[fluffy,label={[name=l2]left:n2-label}] at (0,0) (n2) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
                          & title2                  \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}   \\
    \cline{2-2}
                          &
    Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah
    \blinditemize
    \\
    \cline{2-2}
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw (n1) -- (n2);
    \draw ([yshift=-0.05cm]n2.south) -- ([yshift=-3cm]n2.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a job for `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.70\textwidth}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture},
    fluffy/.style={fill opacity=0.1,circle,fill,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=1mm}}

\blindtext

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l @{~} |X| @{}}
    \cline{2-2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(l1.base)]
        \node[fluffy,label={[name=l1]left:n1-label}] at (0,0) (n1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
                          & \textcolor{red}{title1} \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}   \\
    \cline{2-2}
                          &
    Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah
    \blinditemize
    \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}   \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(l2.base)]
        \node[fluffy,label={[name=l2]left:n2-label}] at (0,0) (n2) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
                          & title2                  \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}   \\
    \cline{2-2}
                          &
    Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah
    \blinditemize\tikzmarknode{aux}{$\vphantom{x_y}$}
    \\
    \cline{2-2}
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw (n1) -- (n2);
    \draw ([yshift=-0.05cm]n2.south) -- (n2.south|- aux.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM** A version with `\tikzmark` instead of `\tikzmarknode`, which *should* work with the older versions of `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.70\textwidth}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture},
    fluffy/.style={fill opacity=0.1,circle,fill,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=1mm}}

\blindtext

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l @{~} |X| @{}}
    \cline{2-2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(l1.base)]
        \node[fluffy,label={[name=l1]left:n1-label}] at (0,0) (n1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
                          & \textcolor{red}{title1} \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}   \\
    \cline{2-2}
                          &
    Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah
    \blinditemize
    \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}   \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(l2.base)]
        \node[fluffy,label={[name=l2]left:n2-label}] at (0,0) (n2) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
                          & title2                  \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}   \\
    \cline{2-2}
                          &
    Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah
    \blinditemize\tikzmark{aux}
    \\
    \cline{2-2}
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw (n1) -- (n2);
    \coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-1mm]pic cs:aux);
    \draw ([yshift=-0.05cm]n2.south) -- (n2.south|- aux2.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @marmot it works as expected but I get some errors in overleaf: Undefined control sequence (line 43), Package pgf Error: No shape named aux is known. (line 46) Should I worry about them?

Comment: @Rod Most likely overleaf does not yet have the latest version of `tikzmark` in it, in which the command `\tikzmarknode` is defined. I will add a solution that *should* work with the old version of `tikzmark`.

Comment: @Rod I added a version without `\tikzmarknode`. Could you please check if it works on overleaf (I never use overleaf)?

Comment: It works like a charm. It seems I had some issue with the new macro ikzmarknode. Thank you again.